# Return R object to Ruby environment

Tags: ruby, r, amazon-s3

I am running R code within a Ruby script. The R code creates a JSON object, which to be returned to the Ruby environment so that it can eventually be encoded and uploaded to an amazon S3 instance.

Here's a sample Ruby script:

```
require "rinruby"
#Use R code
R.eval <<EOF
   counter <- counts
   source(file="rubytest.r")
EOF
```

And here's the sample R script that the Ruby script calls:

```
library("jsonlite")
ls <- list("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
testJSON <- toJSON(ls)

print(testJSON)
```

I'm guessing the print() command isn't the way to go. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully found a way to pass a simple JSON object from the R environment to the Ruby environment:

```
require "rinruby"
require "json"

R.eval <<EOF
   library("jsonlite")
   ls <- list("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
   testJSON <- as.character(toJSON(ls))
EOF

data = JSON.parse R.testJSON
puts data
```

The key was forcing the JSON output to be a character class in the R section of the code using the as.character() function. Not sure if this will work with more sophisticated JSON objects though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the example provided in the Gem's [readme file](https://github.com/clbustos/rinruby#readme), you can just assign values in the R code block and access those through `R`:

```
 R.eval <<EOF
   library("jsonlite")
   ls <- list("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
   testJSON <- toJSON(ls)
 EOF

 data = JSON.parse R.testJSON
```

*(I might add that this is just a wild guess—I didn't actually test this.)*

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I get the error "Error in writeBin(var, .RINRUBY.PULL.SOCKET, endian = "big") : can only write vector objects"